# iOS Quickblox chat : getting error: Code=-999 "You need to enable stream management to use this feature

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, quickblox

I have used Quickblox for implementing chat feature in one of my client's iPhone application.
The chat feature used to work fine initially for a few weeks, but suddenly it has stopped working:

I am getting the following error:
Code=-999 "You need to enable stream management to use this feature

I really need to know from where to enable this feature?
Is it from the admin panel or from the code?
Please guide me with appropriate steps to resolve this issue asap.
I will be thankful.

I am sending the message as:

```
    QBChatMessage * messageToSend = [QBChatMessage message];
    messageToSend.recipientID = self.mRecieverQBUser.ID;
    messageToSend.text = message;
    messageToSend.senderID = qbUser.ID;
    messageToSend.customParameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"YES" forKey:@"save_to_history"];
    [[QBChat instance] sendMessage:messageToSend sentBlock:^(NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"ERROR %@", error)
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call this after you login to chat:

```
[QBChat instance].streamManagementEnabled = YES;
```

Also, using this method is Deprecated in 2.3. Use 'sendMessage:sentBlock:' in QBChatDialog class.